# NoSuchPropertyException in signed build

Tags: android

I am animating a Map Marker via the following code:

```
final Property<Marker, LatLng> property =
        Property.of(Marker.class, LatLng.class, "position");
final ObjectAnimator animator =
        ObjectAnimator.ofObject(otherMarker, property, typeEvaluator, toLatLng);
```

This works fine in a debug build but fails with the following stack trace in a signed build:

```
0   
android.util.NoSuchPropertyException: No accessor method or field found for property with name position
1   
at android.util.ReflectiveProperty.<init>(ReflectiveProperty.java:71)
2   
at android.util.Property.of(Property.java:55)
3   
at com.myapp.fragment.MapWrapperFragment.j(MapWrapperFragment.java:1090)
4   
at com.myapp.ActivityA.l(ActivityA.java:860)
5   
at com.myapp.fragment.FragmentA$22.onClick(FragmentA.java:377)
6   
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
7   
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
8   
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
9   
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
10  
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
11  
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
12  
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
13  
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
14  
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
15  
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
16  
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What could be the reason for this? I am not sure if it's relevant, but I am using Proguard.

Comment: I am getting same issue in marker animation while using proguard. Can you please let me know what rule you used for -keep or -keepnames as suggested by matiash.

Comment: Thanks. I used the information at http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#Proguard

Comment: Are you using google maps 7.0.0 ? I used your proguard settings, but I still get the error, maybe they changed something internally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Proguard is either removing or renaming the field, since it doesn't know about any access done via reflection. That's why it fails at runtime.

You should probably add a `-keep` (or `-keepnames`) rule to prevent this.

Answer (score 10):

I stumbled across the same issue but the provided proguard changes did not do it for me. I guess because I use the new play services ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7.0.0') and they probably have a different internal structure

What worked for me was:

```
-keep class com.google.android.gms.** { *; }
```